# How to use orderby with 2 fields in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have these values in a database table

```
id = 1
StartDate = 1/3/2010
EndDate =  1/3/2010

id = 2
StartDate = 1/3/2010
EndDate = 1/9/2010
```

Now I have so far this orderby for my linq

```
var hold = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();
```

I want to order it however also using the end date.

Like so the order I would want this in as

```
id 2
id 1
```

So `endDates` that are greater go first. I am not sure if I need to change this to use some compare function or something.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

```
MyList.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 85):

Use [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534736.aspx):

```
var hold = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.EndDate)
                 .ToList();
```

You can also use query syntax and say:

```
var hold = (from x in MyList
           orderby x.StartDate, x.EndDate descending
           select x).ToList();
```

`ThenByDescending` is an extension method on [`IOrderedEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852(VS.95).aspx) which is what is returned by [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx). See also the related method [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx).

Comment: thank you - would you also know the type of structure hold is? A list of MyList items?

Answer (score 25):

If you have two or more field to order try this:

```
var soterdList = initialList.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).
                                    ThenBy(x => x.ArrivalDate).
                                    ThenBy(x => x.ShipDate);
```

You can add other fields with clasole "ThenBy"

Answer (score 15):

```
MyList.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.EndDate);
```

Note that you can use as well the Descending keyword in the OrderBy (in case you need). So another possible answer is:

```
MyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 6):

VB.NET

```
 MyList.OrderBy(Function(f) f.StartDate).ThenByDescending(Function(f) f.EndDate)
```

OR

```
  From l In MyList Order By l.StartDate Ascending, l.EndDate Descending
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `From l In MyList Order By l.StartDate Ascending Order By l.EndDate Descending` and `From l In MyList Order By l.StartDate Ascending, l.EndDate Descending`?

Comment: @Oleksandr Yes, Abdul's variant is equivalent to merely doing the second order, so it's not correct.

Comment: @John and @ oleksandr Thanks for identifying the mistake not it has been corrected