# How can I sort on multiple fields with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help by showing me how to sort a LINQ expression.

I have the following:

```
 .OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey)
 .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
           {
               PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
               RowKey = t.RowKey,
               Row = index + 1,
               ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,

           })
```

What I would like to do is to do a sort on the following:

1) First four characters or field RowKey
2) ShortTitle

I am not sure how to do a sort on just a few characters and also not sure how to do a secondary sort.

Comment: try .OrderByDescending(item => {item.RowKey,item.ShortTitle })

Comment: Use the ThenBy [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use orderby with 2 fields in linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989674/how-to-use-orderby-with-2-fields-in-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first four characters, include that in your existing statement, then add the ShortTitle afterwards

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0,4))
.ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that an exception will be thrown if the length of item.RowKey is < 4

Answer (score 1):

You can use OrderByDescending(...).ThenBy()...

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, Math.Min(4, item.RowKey.Length)))
.ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle)
.Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
       {
           PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
           RowKey = t.RowKey,
           Row = index + 1,
           ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,

       })
```

Hth
Tobi

Comment: But I only now want to sort on the first four characters of RowKey.

Comment: item.Rowkey.Substring(0, Math.Min(4, item.RowKey.Length))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) and [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341945) for adding a second key for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.ThenBy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743)

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey)
.ThenByDescending(item => item.ShortTitle)
 .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
           {
               PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
               RowKey = t.RowKey,
               Row = index + 1,
               ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,

           })
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first requirement, sorting by a substring, you can pass `Substring` into the expression tree:

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
```

(But be aware of out of bounds exceptions.)

For the secondary sort, use [the `ThenBy()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743):

```
.ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle)
```

Combined:

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
.ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle)
.Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
       {
           PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
           RowKey = t.RowKey,
           Row = index + 1,
           ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,

       })
```